# table creation using glui

Tags: opengl, glui

Is it possible to create table(mathematical table not kitchen table) by using glui? Please specify the function, if possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [table in opengl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310921/table-in-opengl)

Comment: Yes, I asked the question, but now my question is, is it possible in glui

Comment: Will anyone please create a glui tag

Comment: Sorry, but can you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: what creating a tag or a table?

Comment: I requested to create a tag because I cant create it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience with glui, and looking over the docs again, there doesn't seem to be a way to create a table.

One option is to just pack read only text boxes in a regular grid.. That would sort of poorly mimic a table.

Another option if you are getting to a point where glui simply isn't powerful enough is to switch to something like gtk or gtkmm. It would still allow you to render opengl (through gtkglext), but it would also enable you to use all of the gtk widgets (here's a gallery: http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/2.21/ch02.html -- not that I see a table there either).

Again from my experience, gtk is quite a bit harder to start using as compared to glui, but i think it's worth the effort for an involved gui.